# Pyro4, object changes class (the State patern) but Proxy does not see it

Tags: python, class, proxy, state, pyro

In an application I use a low level library and run it in a separate process.
The connection to the process is done with `Pyro4`.

The library needs initialization before the work and release of resources after.
Thus, I implement the State pattern to have both states nicely separated.

The library is embedded into an object (which is called by `Pyro4.Daemon`). It has initialization method, which does necessary procedures and changes the `__class__` of the object to the "ready" one, which has all the methods to call the library.

However, `Pyro4.Proxy` does not see the object change its' methods after the initialization method is called. Though, if you look at the actual object (in a separate interpreter, running the `Pyro4.Daemon` in a thread) -- the `__class__` does change and everything is fine there. The problem is on `Pyro4.Proxy` side.

**So, is it possible to change the `__class__` when working with `Pyro4`? Am I just doing something wrong?**

PS

It seems `Pyro4.Proxy` grabs the methods of the remote object when you call it the first time. And then the methods are frozen. Could I "refresh" this procedure somehow, ask `Proxy` to check out the methods again?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! So the answer is to run:

```
pyro_proxy._pyroGetMetadata()
```

it grabs the metadata about the remote object and fills the methods of `Pyro4.Proxy` object.

Links:

- [PYRO Implementation](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro/11-implementation.html)
- The code (it's Python-only package!), in your installation or on [repository](https://github.com/irmen/Pyro4)

Comment: You're linking to the documentation of the obsolete version 3 of Pyro. It is likely you meant to link to the Pyro4 docs instead, such as http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/clientcode.html?highlight=metadata#metadata-from-the-daemon